# Quick access to special characters, ideally from the taskbar (Windows 10)

Tags: special-characters

I have the following problem: I regularly need to use a variety of maybe 10 special characters in emails, text files, and so on. They are not located on my keyboard and I don't want to memorize the keyboard ALT codes for them (sometimes I use them very frequently during a week, then not at all for a month and son on).

I usually end up searching for the special characters on the Internet and then copying them, which requires me to open the browser, search for the character in question, locate it, and copy it.

The character map included in Windows does not help me, as I would need to search for the special characters within that map as well. I haven't found a solution yet that is easily accesible from within all programs.

Ideally I would like to have a one-click solution (possibly straight from the taskbar of Windows 10), to just click and thereby copy the special character.

Comment: Simple but rather manual solution - paste them into a txt file, then at least they're all in one place.

Comment: Thank you, yes, that would be better than nothing.

Comment: You could add the alt codes next to each character - you might end up remembering them all eventually, without even trying.

Comment: Nice idea. Would you care to make this an answer, I could upvote it than.

Answer (score 1):

From comments - this is a frame challenge rather than a true answer.

You could make your own text file with each character copy/pasted & even put the alt codes by the side so you may eventually just learn them through familiarity, without really trying.